# How can I make a task scheduler for two groups of tasks with different priorities

Tags: c++, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, multitasking

I'm a beginner to multithreading and task scheduling. At the moment I want to make a task scheduler (in C++) to periodically execute two groups of tasks that have two priorities (i.e., tasks in group 1 have a higher priority than those in group 2, and all tasks within a group have the same priority).

The tasks need to be executed in a correct sequence based on the hierarchy of data flow. For example at each time step task 2 does not become ready for execution until task 1 (task 1 calculates the input data to task 2) has completed its execution (so this means task 2 is triggered by task 1). A task can be triggered by another task with the same or higher priority but not by one with the lower priority.

I have two ideas for the scheduler. The first idea is to create one thread for each group of tasks. For each thread there is a queue for tasks that are ready, and this queue is executed in a FIFO sequence. In addition, there is also a container for tasks that are still waiting for its parent class to finish the data calculation. A class will be set ready and pushed to the ready queue once its parent class completes the calculation.

The second idea is to run each individual task on a separate thread. The thread/tasks that are not ready will simply sleep (e.g., blocked by a semaphore) until the data is ready.

I'm in favor of the first idea however it is more complicated to realize. The second idea is easier to realize but the program will end up having too many threads if I have many tasks. I'm not sure if this causes more overhead during the cyclic execution. Could someone please shed light on it?

Comment: This is going to be opinion-based, but I would definitely go for the first approach. Having many threads around that are simply idle or sleeping most of the time is just silly, IMHO.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thanks for your input! I also think the second idea is a bit silly... I'm just curious about how much more overhead this could cause